# How do I add particles to my Skybox in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, particle-system, particles

Hey stackoverflow community! Currently, my game has a skybox that is plain and gray. What I would like to do is add small moving particles in the skybox to make the game atmosphere better. Is there a simple way to implement particles to your skybox or do you have to do it by hand? If I have to do it by hand, how do I make a particle object?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
E.W

Comment: The easiest way is to implement a particle system in your game (not in your skybox). If you are working on a 2D game that is using a solid color for camera background, I guess the rectangle shape will fit you well, if you are creating your game on 3D, it's even easier and most of the shapes will help you, although I highly recommend using the sphere and instantiating your particles with random position and acceleration. To create a particle system is very simple: GameObject > Effects > Particle System.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to add particles to skybox (you'd have to write a shader for that), its much easier to just create a particle system or (a few) on the outskirts of your scene